# JavaScript RegEx end of string not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to redirect certain facebook urls. So far I have a working [chrome plugin](https://github.com/lony/facebook-hopper), but some urls are not matched the right way.

```
var patternURL = new RegExp("http(s)?://www\.facebook\.com(/|/@?ref=(tn_tnmn|logo)+)?$", "m");
```

Should match:

> https://www.facebook.com/?ref=tn_tnmn 
>   https://www.facebook.com/?ref=logo 
>   https://www.facebook.com/ 
>   https://www.facebook.com

But not:

> https://www.facebook.com/messages/

It seams in JavaScript the end of string (**$**) is not recognized correctly. Thats what my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRm7U/1/) demo shows so far. It should be True but is always false even with "m".

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the Kleene star (i.e. `*`)?

Comment: Like this "http(s)?://www\.facebook\.com(/|/@?ref=*)$"? Yes.

Comment: maybe because you have the `@` in `/@?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` is not escaped. You need to use two backslashes to escape it.

`patternURL = new RegExp("http(s)?://www\.facebook\.com(/|/\\?ref=(tn_tnmn|logo)+)?$", "m");`

http://jsfiddle.net/tRm7U/8/

This is because when you use the regexp constructor, you use a string, and the first backslash is "used" to escape in the string before the regexp object is constructed. You don't need it if you declare it like this:

`patternURL = /http(s)?://www\.facebook\.com(/|/\?ref=(tn_tnmn|logo)+)?$/m`

Comment: you still need to provide the "/" in front of "\\?"

Comment: Thank you! I now use this "^https?://www\\.facebook\\.com(/(\\?.*)?)?$" which uses your idea.